# Datetime pandas stopped matching because a period

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a CSV file with dates in 'es_VE.UTF-8' format like this

[image: Dates with period]

So I use this code to format them:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'es_VE.UTF-8') 
report['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(report['Date'], format = '%d %b %Y')
```

But today stopped working as they changed the format and get rid of the period in this way:

[image: New format]

I have tried some countries and formats but I cannot find the one that is suitable for this.

Is there any way to format this kind of date?
The other options I came up with was casting date as a string and adding the point or make a dictionary, but I'm looking for a more efficient way.

Thank you so much,

A.

Comment: Because of the set.locale, as in Venezuela they put the date in that format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just letting `pd.to_datetime` infer the format works fine for me:

```
import locale
import pandas as pd

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'es_ES') 

pd.to_datetime(['29 oct. 2020', '29 oct 2020'])
# DatetimeIndex(['2020-10-29', '2020-10-29'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

*pandas 1.1.2 with Python 3.8.5 x64 on Win 10*